# Converting a YYYYMMDDXXXXXX into a workable Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

[image]Alright I know many of my questions are based on date formats but here is my problem. I am working with a field, lets call it `ABCTIME`, its saved in numeric format and is displayed as such `20110517151750` ie `2011-05-17:15:17:50`. I need to be able to convert this into a date or `datetime` so I can use a `datediff` to show all records that are greater than or = to todays date (`GETDATE`). Also, I cannot change the format of the table. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks -

edit- I need to show all records that are 1 year or greather than todays date.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Honestly, we don't know most of your questions are based on date formats.

Comment: which language you are using

Comment: @vels4j Wild guess, but probably `sql`.

Answer (score 2):

it would be far more efficient to convert getdate() into YYYYMMDDXXXXXX to filter for greater than or = to today instead of converting your data to suit that one condition.

**edit**- to show all records that are 1 year or greather than todays date

```
SELECT
    *
FROM your_table
WHERE yyyymmddxxxxxx >= cast( convert(varchar, dateadd(YEAR,1,getdate()) ,112) AS bigint) * 1000000
```

Your sample did not have anything beyond 2012 so I changed one to 2015, here are the results:

```
    CREATE TABLE sample_data
        ([Case] int, [Service] varchar(13), [DateInt] bigint)
    ;

    INSERT INTO sample_data
        ([Case], [Service], [DateInt])
    VALUES
        (1, 'CHAMP VA', 20120928073334),
        (2, 'MACSIS-MH POS', 20120927103950),
        (3, 'MACSIS-MH POS', 20150927084716)
    ;

**Query 1**:

    --YYYYMMDDXXXXXX
    SELECT
           DateInt
         , convert(date,convert(varchar,DateInt / 1000000),112) as_date
         , DateInt / 1000000                                    as_int_yyymmdd
    FROM sample_data
    WHERE DateInt >= cast( convert(varchar, dateadd(YEAR,1,getdate()) ,112) AS bigint) * 1000000


**[Results][2]**:

    |        DATEINT |    AS_DATE | AS_INT_YYYMMDD |
    |----------------|------------|----------------|
    | 20150927084716 | 2015-09-27 |       20150927 |
```

see [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7dc92/1)

Comment: Do you have any evidence to support that it would be more efficient to convert `GETDATE()` to OP's format?

Comment: Hello, No the time is not important but if its easier to convert with the time then it doesnt really matter.

Comment: evidence?
"sargable": the question refers to selection of information >= getdate()
so unless there is only one record in the table, applying functions to convert the data will be executed far more than some functions executed against a single system variable, and by avoiding functions on the data existing indexes may be utilized.

Comment: Tried this. Returned 0 results. No errors but no field with a date. I know there should be a few thousand records with the parameter I specified....Any other options? Appreciate it.

Comment: can you provide some sample data?

Comment: Case # Service Date
1 CHAMP VA                       20120928073334
2 MACSIS-MH POS                  20120927103950
3 MACSIS-MH POS                  20120927084716

Comment: please look at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3f513/2

I'll look at your data and get back to you

Comment: by the way, you have asked for records that are greater then getdate() + 1 year; and the dateadd(year,1,getdate() ) does exactly that. IF yo uare after records greater than one year ago instead then the dateadd uses a minus one. dateadd(year,-1,getdate() )

Comment: Tried this. Got the following error   Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: would have to see data data for that conversion error, problem is that an integer does not have to comply with date/time 'rules' e.g. could have an  "hour" of 67 or "day" of 45 which would fail at conversion.

Answer (score 2):

You can create function like this:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION udf_convert_int_date (@date_in INT)  
RETURNS datetime 
AS 
BEGIN 
   DECLARE @date_out datetime 
   SET @date_out = CONVERT(datetime, CAST(@date_in AS CHAR(8)), 101) 

   RETURN @date_out 
END
```

Answer (score 2):

The date in it's current format could be queried.  I don't see why you would need to reformat the date.  If today's date minus 1 year is Dec 31,2012 (20121231000000) return all records where ABCTIME >= 20121231000000.

Comment: right but this query will be plugged into Business Intel. Dev. Studio to be used in future reporting so the data needs to move daily with the date.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be pretty, but if this is always a set format and characters for each section, could you simply break it up using substring or similar function? In SQL Server to convert the date to the 120 format (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss) this would be something like:

```
SELECT
    -- 20110517151750 to 2011-05-17 15:17:50
    SUBSTRING('20110517151750', 1, 4) AS Year,
    SUBSTRING('20110517151750', 5, 2) AS Month,
    SUBSTRING('20110517151750', 7, 2) AS Day,
    SUBSTRING('20110517151750', 9, 2) AS Hour,
    SUBSTRING('20110517151750', 11, 2) AS Minute,
    SUBSTRING('20110517151750', 13, 2) AS Second,
    CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING('20110517151750', 1, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING('20110517151750', 5, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING('20110517151750', 7, 2) + ' ' + SUBSTRING('20110517151750', 9, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING('20110517151750', 11, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING('20110517151750', 13, 2), 120) AS ParsedDate
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQLServer 2008 and beyond it now has a Date datatype which contains only a date with no time. So you can do the following:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, getdate())
```

Comment: Can you explain please,  am i missing something :-)?

Comment: you would replace getdate() with whatever date you want to have converted.  In your case it would be ABCTIME

Comment: I am a newbie in SQL, You certain about it ? Can you post an example using  `20110517151750` this type of field ?

Comment: Just test it out and see if it works for you.  Try something like 
`SELECT CONVERT(date, MyTableName.ABCTIME) FROM MyTableName` or if that doesn't work try `SELECT CONVERT(date, MyTableName.ABCTIME, 110) FROM MyTableName`.  Also take a look at the [**documentation**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) if you want a different format.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT, using ISDATE() makes sense for validation, change of approach.

With respect to that conversion error, all I can assume is that some data doesn't meet some date/time 'rules'. With that in mind perhaps try something like this for discovery of those conditions. It's simplistic but may be helpful. Note you could do this as a count(*) first as I'm unaware how many records you are dealing with and won't say that this will be super quick.

```
SELECT
  yyyymmddxxxxxx
, CASE WHEN isdate( (yyyy + '0101') ) = 0
            OR ( yyyy < '1960' OR yyyy > '2020' ) THEN yyyy ELSE '' END AS yyyy
, CASE WHEN isdate( (yyyy + mm + '01') ) = 0      THEN mm ELSE '' END AS mm
, CASE WHEN isdate( (yyyy + mm + dd) ) = 0        THEN dd ELSE '' END AS dd
, CASE WHEN ( hh > '23' )                         THEN hh ELSE '' END AS hh
, CASE WHEN ( mi > '59' )                         THEN mi ELSE '' END AS mi
, CASE WHEN ( ss > '59' )                         THEN ss ELSE '' END AS ss
FROM your_table
CROSS apply (SELECT convert(varchar(14), yyyymmddxxxxxx)) AS ca1 (int2str)
CROSS apply (SELECT
                     substring(int2str, 1,4) -- yyyy
                   , substring(int2str, 5,2) -- mm
                   , substring(int2str, 7,2) -- dd
                   , substring(int2str, 9,2) -- hh
                   , substring(int2str,11,2) -- mi
                   , substring(int2str,13,2) -- ss
             ) AS ca2 (yyyy,mm,dd,hh,mi,ss)
WHERE ISDATE(convert(varchar(8),int2str,112)) = 0
OR ISDATE( (hh + ':' + mi + ':' + ss) ) = 0
OR         ( yyyy < '1960' OR yyyy > '2020' ) -- arbitrary, ignore of change to suit
;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9ab73/1 output is like this:

```
| YYYYMMDDXXXXXX | YYYY | MM | DD | HH | MI | SS |
|----------------|------|----|----|----|----|----|
| 99990410123456 | 9999 |    |    |    |    |    |
| 20149910123456 |      | 99 | 10 |    |    |    |
| 20140499123456 |      |    | 99 |    |    |    |
| 20140410993456 |      |    |    | 99 |    |    |
| 20140410129956 |      |    |    |    | 99 |    |
| 20140410123499 |      |    |    |    |    | 99 |
| 20140231123499 |      |    | 31 |    |    |    |
```